# MD5 Hash Faster

Tags: java, optimization, hash, md5

I have a wordlist with ~68000 words from level 20 at 0xf.at and want to hash two words to get a hash. Then compare this hash to an existing hash until i found the two words.

I have tried it in java but I am unexpirenced and it is to slow.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/Trojan/Desktop/wordlist.txt"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        Hash h = new Hash();
        String myHash = "cd48323bcf01557f5deadc2ec301affb";
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        String lines[] = everything.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (int j = 1; j <= 68848; j++) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 68847; i++) {
                //System.out.println(i+":"+lines[i]+" "+j+":"+lines[j]);
                if (h.getHash(lines[i]+lines[j],  "MD5") == myHash){
                    System.out.println(lines[i]+lines[j]);
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the md5 hash function i took from an exmaple of stackoverflow:

```
public class Hash {
/**
 * 
 * @param txt, text in plain format
 * @param hashType MD5 OR SHA1
 * @return hash in hashType 
 */
public static String getHash(String txt, String hashType) {
    try {
                java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(hashType);
                byte[] array = md.digest(txt.getBytes());
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                    sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
             }
                return sb.toString();
        } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            //error action
        }
        return null;
}

public static String md5(String txt) {
    return Hash.getHash(txt, "MD5");
}

public static String sha1(String txt) {
    return Hash.getHash(txt, "SHA1");
}
}
```

How can I get this faster?

Comment: Why won't you use `java.security.MessageDigest`? These are likely optimized.

Comment: First problem - you're comparing string references with `==`, so it's not going to match anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You create too many temporary objects inside method getHash. Try reduce. E.g.

```
private static final char[] HEX ={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f',};
public static String getHash(String txt, MessageDigest md) {
    byte[] array = md.digest(txt.getBytes());
    char[] result = new char[array.length*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        byte b = array[i];
        result[2*i] = HEX[(b&0x0f0)>>>4];
        result[2*i+1] = HEX[b&0x0f];
    }
    return new String(result);
}
```

**EDIT**
Moreover you do not need String objects at all. You should return byte[] and use Arrays.equals method.